# Не получается корректно залить проект на GitHub

Tags: github

Приветствую.

Прошу подсказать.

Заливал проект уже 10 раз, и так и сяк пробовал. Но проблема остается. Одна папка в проекте копируется на ГитХаб без внутренних файлов, т.е. папка копируется, но пустая. Остальные папки и файлы копируются нормально. В чем может быть проблема?
Скриншот прилагаю. [image: DataProject] - DataProject - пробемная папка.

Comment: Как заливаете, что показывает git status?

Comment: Git Bash  Пишет такое : $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   DataProject (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 Я заходил отдельно в папку DataProject, там add . и там же коммитил. Тогда писало что все ок, красное уведомление пропадало.

Comment: это же сабмодуль

Comment: т.е. его надо отдельно добавлять коммитить и как-то соединять с остальным проектом?

Comment: то, что у вас часть файлов не попало означает, что вы их не добавили в индекс гита (`git add`) и не зафиксировали (`git commit`)

Comment: я добавлял и коммитил весь проект, почему часть папок и файлов тогда добавилась, а часть нет? Я даже отдельно заходил в папку с которой проблемы и там добавлял и коммитил.